# Non database item in a master detail form

Tags: sql, oracle, forms, oracle11g, oracleforms

In master detail form, it shows if the account was debit or a credit with the id. I want to remove debit and credit columns and add display item to show keyword debit or credit for the account in master form. I'm adding a photo to explain this more 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtSfu.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you stuck?

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do it i 'm m new to oracle

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? No ideas? No approaches?
Then maybe you shoud first buy a book, which helps you understand, what oracle is, and what you can do with it and how.

Comment: i have tried if statement but it didn't work as a trigger after query

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a block named `Voucher` having items inside the frame titled as `Voucher`.

First of all it seems that you don't want to show if `debit > 0 or credit >0`, then you need to hide these columns. As an example, you may hide them by setting their `Canvas` to `<null>` in the `Physical part` of `Property Palette`.

Then define a `POST-QUERY` trigger at the `Voucher`'s block level

( that provides your defined code running after `go_block('voucher'); execute_query;` command block triggered )

with the following code (assume that the extra added display item is named as result ):

```
begin
   :voucher.result := null;
  if nvl(:voucher.debit,0) >0 then
   :voucher.result := 'Debit   '; 
  end if;

  if nvl(:voucher.credit,0) >0 then
   :voucher.result := :voucher.result||'Credit';
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: i want to hide debit and credit columns and in the result i want to compare the account that i used in search with debit and credit columns if it matches the credit the result is credit if not the result is debit

Comment: i 'm using this code in when search button pressed
 {:voucher.result := null;
  if :voucher.debit = :block7.account_id then
   :voucher.result := 'Debit   '; 
  end if;

  if :voucher.credit = :block7.account_id then
   :voucher.result := :voucher.result||'Credit';
  end if;  }
the result only appear in the first row

Comment: @AhmedS.Elsenbawy don't put code in `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED`, but put in `POST-QUERY`, instead, that provides your defined code running after `go_block('voucher'); execute_query;`.